# How can I set a breakpoint in a SQL Server stored procedure using VS Code?

Tags: sql-server, visual-studio-code

I've recently been trying to switch to Visual Studio Code, but I found no way of debugging efficiently a stored procedure in SQL Server, all I can think of is using plain ol' print statements.

I have searched for an extension, found the `mssql` one but it looks like it does not allow setting breakpoints... Is there any way I can debug a SQL Server stored procedure using VS Code or do I need to revert to Visual Studio?

Thanks.

Comment: I've never gotten this to work reliably even in the old days of plain Visual Studio and SSMS; it's a challenge to get it to work even on a purely local server, let alone a remote one. It does pay off to invest in ways other than active debugging to troubleshoot sprocs, as those ways will always work. I've found that breaking up the sproc into individual statements and running these piecemeal works well enough; to capture actual parameter values passed, Profiler can be used. If you have a complex nest of sprocs calling each other this might not be enough, but that's worth rewriting anyway.